# SSIS 2008 Simple csv file to upload into a database table

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am new to SSIS but have a simple task to complete and a small problem.

I have a Data Flow task that has a Flat File Source connected to a OLE DE Destination object. The CSV file holds a header that matches the columns in the database table.

I initially has some problems with 3 fields in the Destination object as these needed to be converted to datatype [DT_STR] from [DT_WSTR].

My Dataflow objects do not produce any erros in the form of a red cross but when i run the package i get the following message from the Immediate/output Window ...

**Task failed: Employee Load
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.**

In the properties pant of the DFT i have increased the MaximunErrorCount to 100 but this is still producing an error.  I only have 1 row of data in the CSV to test the package with so im confused as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: In the `Execution Result tab` along with  the error which u posted you can see other error information which caused the issue . Try to post the actual error

Comment: @praveen  as requested i have added all of the information for the Error.  this info is displayed in the Immediate Window after i have ran the package.

Comment: R u executing your package using `SQL Agent` because AFAIK when executing using BIDS it should display the detail error pertaining to the task

Comment: The error you have posted is misleading. There is another error somewhere in your log that has the true error. You should not increase the error count, you should fix the underlying error so that no errors occur!

Comment: @ElectricLlama the error is a direct copy from the Error Output section?

Answer (score 0):

As this is still an issue i have found an alternative method to complete this task.